# Discord Bot - DirectMessage Command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, command, dm

I'm coding a discord bot in JavaScript.
I try to make commandss that work in Direct Message but when I execute commands in Direct Message, the bot does not respond (as if it does not detect messages sent in DM). Which blocks the progress of the script.

I set the intents when the bot starts.

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages
    ]
});
```

I tried the "if (message.channel.type === 'DM')"

```
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.channel.type === 'DM' && message.content === '-hi') {
        try {
            await message.channel.send(':white_check_mark: | You have enabled the `-hi` command in server mode.');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('error :', error);
        }
    }
});
```

I also tried "if (!message.guild)"

```
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (!message.guild && message.content === '-hi') {
        try {
            const user = message.author;
            await user.send(':white_check_mark: | You have enabled the `-hi` command in server mode.');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('error :', error);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make bot receive DM on Discord js v14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73943125/how-can-i-make-bot-receive-dm-on-discord-js-v14)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include partials in your intents.

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
   ...
  ],
  partials: [
    Partials.Channel
  ]
})
```

You can read more about partials [by clicking here.](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#enabling-partials)